# Max-width properly gets thrown off after using border-top and border-left?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to build a footer for my page. I have a div with a content class which should center with a max-width of 1400. After using border on the parent element, width seems to get thrown off. Screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R41P0.jpg

In the first one, the border property is there, while in the second it isn't.

I don't know what should I do to fix it. I find it very strange.

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video, button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/*GENERAL STYLES*/

body {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-size: 10px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 200vh;
}

#container-site {
    font-size: 10px !important;
}

/* UPPER SECTION */
#upper-section {
    background-color: #001a33 !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 85vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*NAVBAR STYLING */
.navbar-custom {
    padding: 3rem 0;
    max-width: 1650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-upper-section {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.navbar-nav > .nav-item {
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-left: 1.2rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
    width: 195px;
}

.logo-roboticson-navbar {
    width: 195px;
}

/*CONTENT STYLING*/

.content {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn-padding {
    padding: 0.75rem 3rem;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.content > .upper-section-wrapper > .btn-primary:hover {
    background: transparent;
}

.content > .upper-section-wrapper > .btn-outline-primary {
    color: #fff;
}

.unghi-upper-section {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-left: 100vw solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid #fff;
}

.upper-section-robot {
    max-width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

.text-upper-section {
    padding-top: 8rem;
}

.upper-section-wrapper { 
    font-size: bold;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #001a33 !important;
}

/*MIDDLE SECTION*/

#middle-section {
    position: relative;
    color: #007bff;
    padding-top: 2rem;
}

.container-fluid-margin {
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

/*CONTENT BLOCK 1*/

.content-block {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.reguli-1,
.reguli-2,
.reguli-3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #bbb;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}

.reguli-1 {
    margin-right: 1rem;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFF00;
}

.reguli-2 {
    margin-right: 1rem;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFA500;
}

.reguli-3 {
    border-top: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

.card-title-non-bootstrap {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #001a33;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.card-content-non-bootstrap {
    color: #191919;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.middle-section-reguli {
    text-align: left;
    color: #001a33;
    margin-left: 6rem;
}

.middle-section-display-custom {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.middle-section-presentation {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.container-content-block {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    color: #001a33;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-content-block-without-padding {
    color: #001a33;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.display-custom {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.conquer-div-front-page {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.fa-trophy-custom {
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.conquer-presentation {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.conquer-presentation-text {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    width: 55%;
}

.learn-presentation {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    color: #001a33;
}

.learn-presentation-text {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    width: 75%;
}

.text-align-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.fa-pencil-custom {
    color: #001a33;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.try-presentation {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    color: #001a33;
}

.try-presentation-text {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    width: 75%;
}

.fa-crosshairs-custom {
    color: #001a33;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*LOWER SECTION*/

#lower-section {
    background-color: #001a33;
    height: 300px;
    border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container-site">
    <div id="upper-section">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar-custom">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo RoboticsOn" class="logo-roboticson-navbar"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-upper-section" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Acasă <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lecţii</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Exerciţii</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-left-custom ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Logare</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Înregistrare</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="upper-section-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-upper-section">
                        <h1 class="display-4">Bine aţi venit!</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Pagina clubului nostru este locul ideal pentru iniţierea dvs în robotică!</p>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-padding" href="#" role="button">Detalii</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-padding" href="#" role="button">Logare</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 image-upper-section">
                        <img src="img/robot.png"  class="upper-section-robot" alt="Robot RoboticsOn">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="unghi-upper-section"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middle-section" class="container-fluid container-fluid-margin">
        <div class="row content-block">
            <div class="col-md-2 reguli-1">
                <span class="card-title-non-bootstrap">Învaţă</span>
                <span class="card-content-non-bootstrap">Eşti dornic de a învăţă? Aici ai ocazia să te iniţiezi în domeniul roboticii alături de alţi elevi pasionaţi!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 reguli-2">
                <span class="card-title-non-bootstrap">Exersează</span>
                <span class="card-content-non-bootstrap">Crezi că ştii destul? Poţi testa acest lucru încercând chestionarele noastre! Nu-ţi face griji, le poţi relua de fiecare dată când greşeşti!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 reguli-3">
                <span class="card-title-non-bootstrap">Obţine experienţă</span>
                <span class="card-content-non-bootstrap">Te simţi pregătit pentru a fi în topul celor mai buni? Răspunde provocărilor noastre şi obţine puncte de experienţă!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="middle-section-reguli">
                    <h1 class="middle-section-display-custom">Experienţa RoboticsOn</h1>
                    <p class="middle-section-presentation">Poţi lua parte în activităţi de învăţare, atât folosind clip-urile de pe YouTube cât şi citind lecţia ca şi text. După ce studiezi un anumit capitol, poţi oricând să faci chestionare pentru a-ţi testa cunoştinţele. Când te simţi pregătit, poţi lua parte în provocări, ce îţi oferă experienţă, pentru a intra în topul celor mai buni!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-block">
            <div class="container-content-block">
                <div class="display-4 display-custom">Proces de învăţare accesibil tuturor</div>
                <div class="lead">Experienţa noastră este prezentată într-un mod non-formal, de către elevi, lucru ce duce la un grad de accesibilitate ridicat</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-block">
            <div class="container-content-block-without-padding">
                <div class="col-md-12 conquer-div-front-page">
                    <i class="fas fa-trophy fa-trophy-custom"></i>
                    <div class="conquer-presentation"><span class="conquer-presentation-text">Urcă pe culmile succesului obţinând un punctaj maxim în toate provocările noastre! Ai face bine să fii bine pregătit, nu poţi relua o provocare!</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-block">
            <div class="col-md-6 mt-5 text-align-center">
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-pencil-custom"></i>
                <div class="learn-presentation"><span class="learn-presentation-text">Toată lumea ştie că pentru a ajunge sus trebuie să munceşti! Pentru a avea cunoştinţele necesare în robotică, îţi recomandăm să parcurgi lecţiile noastre.</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mt-5 text-align-center">
                <i class="fas fa-crosshairs fa-crosshairs-custom"></i>
                <div class="try-presentation"><span class="try-presentation-text">Ai terminat de parcurs o lecţie? Testează cunoştinţele pe care le-ai obţinut într-un chestionar ce îl poţi repeta, ce nu îţi influenţează punctele de experienţă!</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lower-section" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="content">
            s
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why that's happening.
Might as well miss something very basic, like a typo, and I just didn't spot it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: TLDR; Have you used/checked into `box-sizing:border-box` ? [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Answer (score 0):

It is just because you're using `border-right: 100vw` - this is throwing off the content as you're saying to cover the whole div with your border.

An alternative is to put your content in a div underneath your `#lower-section`? I've made an example for you here:

```css
/*LOWER SECTION*/

#lower-section {
  background-color: #001a33;
  border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid #fff;
}

.container-fluid {
  background: #001a33;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.content {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="lower-section" class="container-fluid">

</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="content">
    s
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really like this solution because that would mean separating lower-section from its components. Thanks for your answer though. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to solve a problem like this while don't separating the components from the lower-section div, you can use this:

```css
#lower-section {
    background-color: #001a33;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.angle-lower-section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="lower-section" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="content">
            s    
        </div>
        <div class="angle-lower-section"></div>
    </div>
```